# What's the are the inputs for Raiden's flight in NES-MK3?

Tags: mortal-kombat-3

I searched all of the internet but I didn't find. What is Raiden's flight movement keys in Mortal Kombat 3 for the SNES?

For example Lui-Kang inputs:

```
 Left+Down+A: Flight kick
 Down+Left+A: Throw fire
```

But what is Raiden's inputs?

The AI can make flying movement against me. The game images here:

[image: mortal kombat 3 nintendo emulator]
[image: mortal kombat 3 nintendo emulator]
Thanks.

Comment: From what I can tell, Raiden was not in Mortal Kombat 3.

Comment: According to the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortal_Kombat_3?wprov=sfsi1), Raiden is not a playable character in MK3. I have not (and will not) download the link you posted, but I presume it is a different game that's mislabeled.

Comment: From the wiki, "Carlos Pesina, who played Raiden in the first two games, did not appear in MK3 as a penalty for his involvement in the rival game Tattoo Assassins"

Comment: @kodmanyagha Do not link to piracy sites.

Comment: @nailbones Do **not** be rude and insulting to other users. It goes against our [be nice policy](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), which you should take the time to review.

Comment: it isn'n SNES just NES.

Comment: It this some weird homebrew game? All google result link to ROM-sites. Not a legit site in sight (except for GameFAQs).

Comment: Since this game sounds not official, this Raiden coded for the game might not have this move, anyway. Did the AI used this move against you?

Comment: Yes AI can make. I edited the question and added some image about this.

Comment: Seems this is a [bootleg version](http://bootleggames.wikia.com/wiki/Mortal_Kombat_II_(Hummer_Team)) of some sort (I had a hard time pinning it down, but I think it's a variant of this one). Unfortunately, I've not been able to find a move list for this game. Another version had [this moveset](http://bootleggames.wikia.com/wiki/File:7._Mortal_Kombat_2_Special_Manual_Back.jpg), that seems similar enough to be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

While Raiden is not available in MK3 and I assume this is a mistake on the poster's part, the input for his flight attack in classic MK games is always the same:

`← ← →`

Comment: I tried but didn't work :(